# Does Knockout JS use Key-value Observation for change detection between model and view?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Does Knockout JS use Key-value Observation for change detection between model and view?

React JS uses Virtual DOM, Angular1 uses dirty checking, I was curious if Knockout JS uses KVO for change detection: synchronizing model with the view.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code:
http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.4.2.debug.js

When an observable is invoked with a new value, the method observable.isDifferent is called, which in turn invokes the following function, to test if the value is different.

So in answer to your question, if the value you provide is primitive and different, or non primitive, the observable's subscribers will be notified.

```
var primitiveTypes = { 'undefined':1, 'boolean':1, 'number':1, 'string':1 };

function valuesArePrimitiveAndEqual(a, b) {
    var oldValueIsPrimitive = (a === null) || (typeof(a) in primitiveTypes);
    return oldValueIsPrimitive ? (a === b) : false;
}
```